# using Regex replace exactly the dynamic string and not if it is embedded inside another string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Let me explain you my problem using an example:

```
var mainString = "at iteration";

var dynamicString = "at";   // coming from user input
```

Now, I want to prepend `[]` to the `dynamicString` and replace all occurances of `dynamicString`  in `mainString` with this new `dynamicString`.

So, I do:

```
mainString = mainString.replace(new RegExp(dynamicString,"g"), "[]" + dynamicString);
```

My expected result is:

```
[]at iteration
```

But I am getting:

```
[]at iter[]ation
```

This is because there is an `at` inside `iteration`.

Javascript doesnt allow to do something like:

```
new RegExp(/^dynamicString$/,"g") // where dynamicString is a variable
```

Is there a way that I can fix this?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/9g6hk9nu/)

Comment: Downvote without a comment is not acceptable!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check for [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) by using `\b`. So, your regex instantiation would look like

```
new RegExp("\\b" + dynamicString + "\\b","g")
```

A word boundary is a space, hyphen, period and other things along those lines. So in each of these examples, it would match the first instance of `at` but not the second

```
at iteration
at-iteration
.at.iteration
```

Et cetera...

Answer (score 3):

You can use word boundaries as in:

```
mainString = mainString.replace(new RegExp("\\b" + dynamicString + "\\b", "g"), 
     "[]" + dynamicString);
```